# I have a mapply function that works - how do I convert this to a mlply?

Tags: r, algorithm, progress-bar, plyr, mapply

I have written the following R code which allocates the closest postcode to a set of northing / easting coordinates:

```
# Set of northing / easting coordinates that I need to assign a postcode to
x1 <- c(1,2,4,6,7)
y1 <- c(5,2,4,7,8)

# Postcode with northing / easting coordinates
postcode <- c("Postcode A", "Postcode B", "Postcode C", "Postcode D")
x2 <- c(5,3,4,2)
y2 <- c(8,1,2,4)

# Function that attributes closest postcode to (x1, y1) coordinates
algo <- function(x, y)
{
        dist <- which.min(sqrt(((x2 - x)^2) + ((y2 - y)^2)))
}

# mapply to run the function, and find the closest coordinates
postcode[mapply(algo, x1, y1, SIMPLIFY = T)]
[1] "Postcode D" "Postcode B" "Postcode C" "Postcode A" "Postcode A"
```

Since I have over 500,000 (x1, y1) coordinates and over 1,000,000 (x2, y2) coordinates, this mapply function takes a long time to run, and I want to monitor the progress. I understand that the mlply has a progress bar function, but I cannot get it to run. What I have done is:

```
# Using mlply to run the function, and find the closest coordinates with progress bar
library(plyr)
postcode[mlply(cbind(x1, y1), .fun = algo, .progress = "tk")]
```

What am I doing wrong? Would appreciate the correct R code for the mlply (or other m*ply functions), and an explanation on why the above is incorrect.

Many thanks for your time and kind attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have spotted at least two issues.

**First**, the names of your columns in your data frame do not match the name of arguments in your function. The following code works without warning.

```
mlply(cbind(x= x1, y =y1), .fun = algo, .progress = "tk")
```

**Second**, mlply returns a list, with elements that cannot be used to subset your postcode vector:

```
mlply(.data = cbind(x = x1, y = y1), .fun = algo, .progress = "tk")
```

$`1`
[1] 4

$`2`
[1] 2

$`3`
[1] 3

$`4`
[1] 1

$`5`
[1] 1

attr(,"split_type")
[1] "array"
attr(,"split_labels")
  x y
1 1 5
2 2 2
3 4 4
4 6 7
5 7 8

To resolve this I suggest :

```
postcode[unlist(mlply(.data = cbind(x = x1, y = y1), 
    .fun = algo, .progress = "tk"))[1:length(x1)]]
```

**Last**, if you try to look for minimal distance, you may consider looking for the minimal squared distance directly (you avoid computing the square root a million times, which should improve time).